# Cannot assign to read only property 'dataChange' of object '#<ValidationComponent>'

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

I am trying to use a two way binding in Angular 4. Here is my component code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'form-validation',
    templateUrl: './form.validation.template.html',
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class ValidationComponent {

    @Input() data;

    @Output dataChange = new EventEmitter();

    //...

}
```

But when I try to use it on something like it:

```
<form-validation [(data)]="data"></form-validation>
```

I get this error on Chrome's console:

```
Cannot assign to read only property 'dataChange' of object '#<ValidationComponent>'
```

The `data` property is an array of a specific type, but even if I inform this type or inicialize the property the error happens.

Comment: Isn't it `@Output()` instead of `@Output`?

Comment: Exactly! Such stupid mistake. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just to make it clear, the answer below is by [harry ninh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218277/harry-ninh) in a comment above

It should be @Output() instead of @Output